# Creating or editing shredder .bkt opening book

Tags: opening, engines

I want to create an opening book for Shredder or edit an existing one. the way I want it is like how Lucas chess works, giving a certain value (weight, percentage, etc) to a specific move. This is an example from Lucas chess:
[image: Lucas chess polyglot book factory]

I want to do the same thing for Shredder .bkt books.

Shredder has the option to create a new book and then import new games to it. But I don't want to import chess games. so please help me do one of these:

- Convert .bin opening books from Lucas Chess to .bkt (I think shredder can also use .dat, .bok, .cgs and .fbk, but I'm not sure. if there is any way to convert it to those formats please tell me)
- Directly create or edit the .bkt file to achieve the same thing that was done using Lucas chess
- Last effort, an easy way to import games to achieve the same goal (setting exact values for each move by importing many games to the book using shredder itself)